# How to make an SVG glyph (from a font) look like it was handwritten?

Tags: fonts, typography, svg

I want to take [this font](http://www.virtualvinodh.com/wp/tamil-brahmi-font/):

[image]

and make it look more like the handwritten version:

[image]

I don't want to make it look *that* handwritten, but a little rougher curves and more stroke-like tips to the curves rather than so computer-generated looking.

Assuming I have the SVG for a single glyph isolated, how can I apply some sort of effect to the SVG path that makes it look more coarse, more handmade? And then so it can be output as an SVG path as well.

Comment: You're wanting to do this programmatically? or manually?

Comment: I want to run a command or do some action to do it automatically. Doesn't have to be with a programmatic script, but I don't want to manually adjust the points to achieve the effect.

Comment: Perhaps there is some way [noise](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2019/02/19/svg-filter-effects-creating-texture-with-feturbulence/) plays into this.

Comment: Filters like the article you mention could do something along these lines. You'd have to be careful how you're doing it, as the noise could produce things that are no longer connected letters. I might recommend a programmatic changing of their path to bezier curves and then a pseudo-random adjustment of the handles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you convert these glyphs to outlines, it could be done in vector image editing software such as Adobe Illustrator or Inkscape (which is free).

In Inkscape, select the outlines and do *Extensions > Modify Path > Jitter Nodes*. Select the option to "Shift node handles", and adjust the displacement values as required.

[image]

In Illustrator a similar effect is possible with *Effect > Distort & Transform > Roughen*. Choose the "smooth" option, and reduce the size as required.

[image]

Finally in Illustrator to convert the effect to paths, click *Object > Expand Appearance*.

Note: There's no need to do this final step with Inkscape, since the Jitter Nodes Extension modifies the paths directly.

Answer (score 1):

Handwriting-likeness cannot be made by randomly moving the nodes of the glyph paths. A little child who tries to make slowly a freehand copy of the outline of a glyph can produce something which can be simulated by randomly moving the nodes of a path and very likely by increasing the number of the nodes. Established handwriting should look consistent which makes the problem complex. I guess a handwritizing algorithm should be multilevel. It should cause variations to text blocks, text lines, glyphs and the strokes.

You can try to affect the lowest level easily. Try to trace a raster image of a piece of text. Here's one example:

[image]

Tracing deforms tight curves to simpler. Inkscape did this with default settings.

If you are a programmer, you can probably cause size, rotation and placement variations, even envelope distortions. I must skip these.